# Elasticsearch got stack level too deep with google apis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, google-api, rubygems

I've met a problem when using gem google api
My Elasticsearch will get `SystemStackError - stack level too deep`.
I am sure the issue comes up when every time I try to do an operation(calling method) to the object of `Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Results`

#### Structure

```rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  include Searchable::Organization
end
```

```
module Searchable
  module Organization
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
    module ClassMethods
      def es_search(term: nil)
        __elasticsearch__.search(
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: {
                multi_match: {
                  query: term
                }
              },
            }
          },
          size: size
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Gem version

- ruby (2.6.5)
- rails (6.0.3.7)
- elasticsearch-model(7.1.0)
- elasticsearch-rails(7.1.0)
- google-apis-core (0.4.2)
- google-apis-drive_v3 (0.19.0)
- google-apis-slides_v1 (0.12.0)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2022/4/20 Updated:
I've run the same method in the console and it works well.

Comment: It turns out an issue from `new_relic` and elasticsearch is just a trigger.
https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/ruby-agent-module-prepend-alias-method-chains